# VS 2015 - EF Migration commands

Tags: .net-core

Getting following error while executing entity framework migrations

dotnet.exe : System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet ef -`enter code here`-startup-project ../Bloomerang.Web migrations add AssessmentQuestions
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.Argument...cannot be null.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Parameter name: connectionString

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 
sqlServerOptionsAction)

at Bloomerang.Web.Startup.b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 
optionsAction)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ClosedIEnumerableService.CallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.TransientCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes()

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute(CommonOptions commonOptions, String name, String outputDir, String context, String environment, Action`1 
reporter)

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()

at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)

Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: connectionString

Answer (score 0):

Make your appsettings.json resemble this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings":
  {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContosoUniversity1;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
"Logging":
  {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel":
    {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```